# How do I change the background color of a button as I move a slider?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uislider

I currently am struggling to get the background color of my button to change as my slider reaches a certain point. I want the background color to change from orange to blue as my slider value reaches one, but right now it is only changing color if I press the button. Help Please :)

This is what i currently have:

```
- (IBAction)buttonChange:(id)sender {
if ([_statuslabel.text isEqualToString:@"Temperature: 1"]) {
    [_myButton setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blueColor]] ;
```

Comment: Do you want the change to be gradual or abrupt?

Comment: Do you know how to handle changes in the slider's value?

Comment: Please provide more details, are you using a UISlider? In your provided code, you are checking a label's text, how are you updating that text? I'll edit my answer if you provide more details

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the replies. I'm new to all this and would just like the color of my button to change as the slider reaches a certain point (0.5 or halfway) it doesnt need to be fancy. Just an abrupt change from orange to blue as the slider reaches a certain point

Comment: I updated my answer to do exactly this for you.

Answer (score 1):

To get a constant change of your buttons color you could use this code:

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
    CGFloat blueHue = 232.0f;  // should be kind of blue
    CGFloat orangeHue = 32.0f; // should be kind of orange

    CGFloat resultingHue = ((blueHue - orangeHue)) * sender.value + orangeHue;

    self.yourButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:resultingHue / 360.0f
                                                 saturation:1
                                                 brightness:1
                                                      alpha:1];
}
```

Just connect your `UISlider` in `IB` and set the `sliderValueChanged:` method for the `Value Changed` event.

Using the HSV (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) model should be the easiest solution to archive what you want.

Hope this helps

Comment: hi, nice code. But I have doubt here: does self.yourButton.backgroundColor suffice to cause immediate change for UIButton? I don't know, but I have had my share of difficulty making changes to UIButton after it is created.

Comment: Sure, just test out the code. It will give you a steady change in color from blue to orange. Not just a hard cut from one color to the other, but a continuous change based on your slider position. the range of the slider btw. needs to be between 0..1.
I tested it and the button was updated as I was dragging...

Answer (score 0):

From my interpretation of your question, you are using a UISlider and you call this function on touchupinside.

To update it continuously, implement a valuechanged function

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)slider {
    if (slider.value > 0.5)
        slider.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    else
        slider.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
}
```

Then in interface builder connect this to the sliders "Value Changed" outlet

Comment: I have put your code in and it has done exactly what I wanted it to do. You've been a great help, thanks